# Flask "url_for" equivalent for Falcon

Tags: python, rest, http, falconframework

I'm new to [Falcon](http://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and I was wondering if there was a Flask-like "url_for" solution for the framework. I've scoured the docs and I can't seem to find anything relevant with a google/stack search.

To clarify for users of Falcon who haven't used Flask, I would like to dynamically fetch a defined resource's URL. I'm specifically trying to achieve resource expansion, by including a link to my resources within my payload so the frontend doesn't have to construct any URLs.

Code:

```
class PostResource(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp, post_id):
        """Fetch single post resource."""
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        post_dto = post_to_dto(get_post(post_id))
        # TODO: find url_to alternative for falcon: specify post resource location
        post_dto.href = ''
        resp.body = to_json(PostDtoSerializer, post_dto)


class PostCollectionResource(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """
        Fetch grid view for all post resources.

        Note: This endpoint support pagination, pagination arguments must be provided via query args.
        """
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        # TODO: add hrefs for each post for end ui
        post_collection_dto = PostCollectionDto(
        posts=[post_to_dto(post, comments=False) for post in get_posts(
            start=req.params.get('start', None), count=req.params.get('count', None)
        )])

        resp.body = to_json(PostCollectionDtoSerializer, post_collection_dto)

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        """Create a new post resource."""
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_201
        payload = req.stream.read()
        user = req.context.get('user')
        create_post(user._id, from_json(PostFormDtoSerializer, payload))
        # TODO: find url_to alternative for falcon: redirect to on_get
        resp.set_header('Location', '')
```

Post collection example:

```
[
  {
    "href": ".../post/000000/",
    "links": [
      "rel": "like",
      "href": ".../post/000000/like"
     ],
     "title": "Foobar",
     ...
  }
]
```

I would like to be able to generate a link to the `PostResource`.

Comment: If anyone facing the same predicament was curious, I ended up creating a base resource that consumes a URI as well as the Falcon api instance, that automatically passes off the uri to the api instance and initializes the object, as well as contains a helper for constructing urls on the fly.

Comment: https://github.com/neetjn/py-blog/issues/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of closing this thread, I'm now using the methodology detailed here https://github.com/neetjn/py-blog/issues/16.

Falcon does *not* support this as confirmed by the maintainers, my work around was to create a base resource with a static route and child method to construct a link to the given resource using the information from the request's `req` argument.

Example:

```
class BaseResource(object):

    route = ''

    @classmethod
    def url_to(cls, host, **kwargs) -> str:
        return f'{host}{cls.route.format(**kwargs)}'
```

...

```
class PostResource(BaseResource):

  route = '/v1/post/{post_id}'

  def on_get(self, req, res):
      pass


class PostCollectionResource(BaseResource):

  route = '/v1/posts/'

  def on_get(self, req, res):
      posts = get_posts()
      for post in posts:
          post.href = PostResource.url_to(req.netloc, post_id=post.id)
```